# Python Distributive Property on Lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following situation:
a `List[i][j]` like following:

```
 [['Motorized', 'Motorize', 'Motoriz', 'Motori', 'Motor', 'Moto', 'Mot', 'Mo', 'M'],
  ['wheel', 'whee', 'whe', 'wh', 'w'],
  ['chair', 'chai', 'cha', 'ch', 'c']]
```

I want to combine all values in all orders as possible like:

```
Motorized wheel chair, M wheel c, ...
```

Is there a built-in function to do this? Regarding that list can have any dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is for:

```
lst = [['Motorized', ...] ... ]
for combination in itertools.product(*lst):
    print ' '.join(combination)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to get all possible combinations of these lists, you should look at `product`.

```
from itertools import product
lists = [['Motorized', 'Motorize', 'Motoriz', 'Motori', 'Motor', 'Moto', 'Mot', 'Mo', 'M'],
  ['wheel', 'whee', 'whe', 'wh', 'w'],
  ['chair', 'chai', 'cha', 'ch', 'c']]
for combo in product(*lists):
    print combo
```